# Insert a new android contact photo

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have  a problem when I want to insert a photo for a contact.
I want to insert the "parent" contact image, which have no image.

I just want to change the photo of the contact, not the raw contact (contact_id)

It just works for Update, but not for insert, what is wrong ? The photo is not recorded in content providers.

```
//UPDATE
    if (contact.getPhotoURL() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, baos.toByteArray())
                            .build());
        }else{
//INSERT
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, contact.getId())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, baos.toByteArray())
                    .build());
        }
```

Thanks

EDIT :
this following code works

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

    ContentResolver c = ctx.getContentResolver();


ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
int photoRow = -1;
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + personId + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
Cursor cursor = c.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null, null);
int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
}
cursor.close();

values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, personId);
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, baos.toByteArray());
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

if (photoRow >= 0) {
    c.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values, ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null);
} else {
    c.insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

The field IS_SUPER_PRIMARY fixes the problem, the photo is saved for the "global" contact, not just the specific raw_contact.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine........